# switchee code not outputting data

Tags: switchee

This is the first time i've used Switchee and it's not outputting anything.

The code looks correct. Any thoughts?

gallery_type is a P&T Switch field.

(I've simplified the code for sake of the example and it still is not outputting anything.)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="collections" disable="categories|category-fields|member-data|pagination" status="open" limit="1"}
{exp:switchee variable="gallery_type" parse="inward"}
{case value="portrait"}
Portrait
{/case}

{case value="landscape"}
Landscape

{/case}
{/exp:switchee}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this way, the `gallery_type` isn't being parsed by the `exp:channel:entries`.

Try this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="collections" disable="categories|category-fields|member-data|pagination" status="open" limit="1"}
    {exp:switchee variable="{gallery_type}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="portrait"}
            Portrait
        {/case}

        {case value="landscape"}
            Landscape

        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Let me say that if there isn't any other module tags, you could use traditional conditionals and to have the same performance, because `exp:channel:entries` already load everything.

But, if you are using another module inside the `case`s, switchee is a good call.